# How to assign default values for routing parameters in angular.dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Consider the following route config:

```
route
    ..addRoute(
      name: 'custom',
      defaultRoute: true,
      path: '/:param1/:param2',
      enter: view('view/template.html')
    );
```

I am injecting the router into a controller and setting up `router.onRouteStart.listen`, within which I am accessing parameters via `router.activePath.last.parameters`, now, if `param2` is not present in the user entered route, then i want to assign a default value to `param2` (also replace the route). How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more of exploration found this sample on angular.dart.tutorial: 
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/blob/master/Chapter_06/lib/routing/recipe_book_router.dart#L19-L24

Which has the following way of doing it (changes according to my sample code):

```
route
    ..addRoute(
        name: 'default',
        defaultRoute: true,
        path: '/:param1',
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) => 
            router.go('custom', {
                    'param1': router.activePath.last.parameters['param1'],
                    'param2': 'defaultValue'},
                //[Optional, if mounted in a nested route]  
                //startingFrom: router.root.findRoute('custom_head'),
                replace: true))
    ..addRoute(
        name: 'custom',
        defaultRoute: true,
        path: '/:param1/:param2',
        enter: view('view/template.html')
    );
```

If the user doesn't provide a value for param2 then the first route gets activated, which will assign a default value for param2 and force update of url by replacing earlier one.