# AngularDart routes: Optional parameter

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-routing

Is it possible to setup optional route parameters without setting up a secondary route? I want to set up a very simple REST type interface with a path defined as such:

`reports/:reportType/:reportId`

Navigating to `reports/:reportType` will allow listing all completed reports of the specified type and navigating to the full path will bring up that specific report. The first portion I have working fine, however I'm unable to determine how to make the last segment optional.

Using the following route definition, the enter method is only called when all parameters are specified:

```dart
void routesInit(Router router, RouteViewFactory view) {
  view.configure({
    'report' : ngRoute(
        // :rptId cannot be null (aka not provided)
        path: '/reports/:rptType/:rptId',
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) {
          print(e.parameters);
        })
  });
}
```

I've tried standard type optional braces around `:rptId` such as parents `/reports/:rptType(/:rptId)` and square braces `/reports/:rptType(/:rptId)` but to no avail.

I've also tried the following:

```dart
void routesInit(Router router, RouteViewFactory view) {
  view.configure({
    'report' : ngRoute(
        // :rptId cannot be null (aka not provided)
        path: '/reports/:rptType',
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) {
          print(e.parameters);
        },
        mount: {
          'report_type' : ngRoute(
            path: '/:rptId',
            enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) {
              print(e.parameters);
              print(e.route.parent.parameters);
          })
        })
  });
}
```

The problem with the above is that both the `report` and `report_type` enter functions are called so I can't setup the views properly there as I would need some kind of check in the `enter` function of the `report` route to detect if there is a child route, and I'm not sure how that could be accomplished either.

Is there an easier way of specifying an optional parameter or should I look at completely changing the paths I want to use to mitigate the nested/child parameters? (E.G.: use something like `reports/type/:rptType` and `reports/single/:rptId`)

Comment: Isn't this a similar requirement as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871434 ?

Comment: Not exactly it (I'm not interested in a default parameter) but it does strike me now with the glaringly obvious...

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this case is extremely simple. I was over engineering the solution. Simple fix, just use two top-level routes.

```dart
void routesInit(Router router, RouteViewFactory view) {
  view.configure({
    'report' : ngRoute(
        path: '/reports/:rptType',
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) {
          print(e.parameters);
      }),
    'report_id': ngRoute(
        path: '/reports/:rptType/:rptId',
        enter: (RouteEnterEvent e) {
          print(e.parameters);
        })
  });
}
```